# Why sendText calls throw timeout exception when using websockets?

Tags: java, websocket, jboss6.x

I am new to websocket, and trying out with few examples. The application I created works fine for sometime say 10 - 15 mins, and from then on, it throws the timeout exception when sendText method is called on websocket session. I changed the value for "org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT" to -1 and now it hangs. 
could you please help me to resolve this issue.

The code I have written to send the data to websocket is as below:

```
public void update() {
    Dashboard dashboardData = tunnelDataService.getDashboardData();
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer();
    String json = null;
    try {
        json = ow.writeValueAsString(dashboardData);
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (session.isOpen()) {
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText(json);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am deploying this application on JBoss EAP 6.3.

Comment: This is weird. They have updated TomCat to leave a WebSocket open indefinetely a while back. Check if in your server.xml file connectionTimeout is set to -1

Comment: I am using jboss 6.3 EAP. Is there a particular issue with this?